# Creating a HMAC SHA256 hash in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, hash

I am trying to create a hash using PowerShell code to confirm an webhook subscription using Kamstrup READy API. However, I get errors the following error when confirming a subscription.

[image: PowerShell error code]

Then I tried to recreate the example hash in [their documentation (under Confirm)](https://api-eu.ready.kamstrup.com/swagger/index.html). I keep getting a different result that do not match their example hash.

```
$message = @'
{
    "verificationToken" : "e6557603-9121-4c9b-9c38-1a33f56204b0"
}
'@
$secret = '6KVQ05mN9iLvCg=='

$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.key = [Convert]::FromBase64String($secret)
$signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($message.ToString()))
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)

echo $signature

$ExpectedHash = 'jm+Inr5EVDgLHbpZaTVjInllgm8Ogs7Ok9mLePiciNc='
$ReturnedHash = 'Zo5DukhFluumI/RchKOPQOBheY7rlnzOFLD+A0aBbDk='
```

I'm kind of stuck at this point. I expect that it has to do something with the formatting of the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation to which you link states that you must hash the verification token -- not the entire message.

> First **they must take the verificationToken and hash it** using a client secret(Base64 value created in READyManager) and SHA256.

Correcting your code to use just the verification token, I get the expected hash back.

```
# $message = '{ "verificationToken" : "e6557603-9121-4c9b-9c38-1a33f56204b0" }'
$message = 'e6557603-9121-4c9b-9c38-1a33f56204b0'
$secret = '6KVQ05mN9iLvCg=='

$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.key = [Convert]::FromBase64String($secret)
$signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($message.ToString()))
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)

echo $signature

$ExpectedHash = 'jm+Inr5EVDgLHbpZaTVjInllgm8Ogs7Ok9mLePiciNc='
$ReturnedHash = 'Zo5DukhFluumI/RchKOPQOBheY7rlnzOFLD+A0aBbDk='
```

Output:

```
H:\Temp> .\testps.ps1
jm+Inr5EVDgLHbpZaTVjInllgm8Ogs7Ok9mLePiciNc=
```

A simple case of RTFM :-)